# ASP.NET Routing - GetRouteData does not work if path exists

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-routing

I have a `HttpModule` which intercepts all requests and loads data from the database based on routing rules. However, I run into one problem all the time; `GetRouteData` only works if the path does not exist:

```
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

Assuming a request comes in for the url `http://localhost/contact`, I get the correct routing data relating to that url if that path does not exist in the file system. The problem appears when I want to customize the page at that url which I do by creating an aspx page in the path `~/contact/default.aspx`. Once I do that, `GetRouteData` return `null`.

I have even tried creating a new `HttpContext` object, but I still can not retrieve route data if the page exists.

Has anyone ever run into this problem? Is there a solution/workaround?

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles` to true.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    // Cause paths to be routed even if they exists physically
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

    // Map routes
    routes.MapPageRoute("...", "...", "...");
}
```

Beware though. IIS7 behaves a little differently than the server used when debugging within Visual Studio. I got bit by this when I deployed my application to the web. Check out this [feedback I submitted to Microsoft Connection](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/630686/behavior-of-running-asp-net-application-from-visual-studio-different-from-running-on-iis7).

Comment: Hmmm, very helpful indeed! That certainly solved my problem, but unfortunately creates a new problem. When I do that, all my css, js and image files get routed through my routing rules which is not really what I want. I still want the existing files to use the original handler except I just want to obtain the routing values. Is that possible?

Comment: That problem isn't created by routing existing files. It's a separate issue that results from URL routing. I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean about you just want to obtain the routing values.

Comment: Let take for example that I have a "Contact Us" page and I want it to display content from the database as well as a form to submit contact information. If the "Contact Us" page does not exist, I can call: `var pageName = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)).Values["name"];` and retrieve data relating to that page from the database. However, when the page exists, I can not do that since `GetRouteData` returns null. Makes sense?

Comment: I figured it out... Had to add route constraints.

Comment: Good, because I was still having a little trouble understand what you were doing, or why. :-)